# Comparing a boost::optional<T&> to const T&

Tags: c++, templates, boost, operator-overloading, constants

I'm trying to compare a constant reference and a non-constant optional object with the same type.  I have a type, `NonCopy`, which is noncopyable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct NonCopy {
    NonCopy() { }
    NonCopy(const NonCopy&) = delete;
    NonCopy& operator=(const NonCopy&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    NonCopy nc;
    const NonCopy& object = nc;
    boost::optional<NonCopy&> object2 = nc;

    if (!object2 && object2.get() != object) {
        std::cout << "not equal?\n";
    }
}
```

Which yields

```
error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘boost::optional_detail::types_when_is_ref<NonCopy&>::raw_type {aka NonCopy}’ and ‘const NonCopy’)
```

I've tried multiple variations on the theme, including

```
if (object2 && const_cast<const NonCopy&>(object2.get()) != object)
```

Which yields a very interesting error of

```
error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘const NonCopy’ and ‘const NonCopy’)
```

and lists candidates for != on `boost::optional<NonCopy>` (such as `bool boost::operator!=(const boost::optional<NonCopy>&, const boost::optional<NonCopy>&)`), rather than on `NonCopy`.

Comment: Sounds to me like the type is simply not comparable.

Comment: It is... stuck in pointer thinking.  I thought != would compare whether both references pointed to the same object

Comment: @Outurnate: You can find that out, by `&(object2.get()) != &object`.  Or, if you're really paranoid, use `std::addressof`

Comment: addressof... That's a new one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `object2.get()` returns a `NonCopy&`, your example effectively simplifies to:

```
NonCopy nc;
const NonCopy& object = nc;
NonCopy& object2 = nc;

object != object2; // error: no match for operator!=
```

That simply means that your type `NonCopy` has no `operator!=`. Implement that, and your code will compile. `boost::optional` is not relevant here.

Although note that you're checking:

```
if (!object2 && object2.get() != object)
    ^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    object2 is none, but get it anyway?
```

That is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah!  I got it now.  I was under the impression that a reference type would allow me to compare that reference object (that is, that both references refer to the same object, much like a pointer)

Comment: And +1 for finding an unrelated logic error... I'm trying to rid my codebase of naked pointers, and I guess that one slipped through

Comment: @Outurnate Nope, a pointer points to the object but a reference **is** the object. If you want to compare addresses, you'd have to explicitly check `&object` vs `&object.get()`.

Comment: reference is the object is what's throwing me off.  That makes far more sense now.  Thanks!